# What are the systemd command line options "--switched-root" and "--deserialize"?

Tags: linux, systemd

Doing a `ps` on my Linux box shows that `systemd` runs with the command line options `--switched-root` and `--deserialize`.  Nothing in the man page or `/usr/share/doc/systemd` mentions them, and Google hasn't been much help.  So, what do they do?  I'm guessing that `--switched-root` has something to do with [pivot_root](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pivot_root), but that's just a guess.

Comment: Good point, same here on Arch: my process n. 1 is systemd --system --deserialize 18. Again no clue from man.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

These are [intentionally undocumented](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2013-September/013008.html) internal parts of systemd.  Very simply, therefore:

- `--deserialize` is used to restore saved internal state that a previous invocation of `systemd`, `exec()`ing this one, has written out to a file.  Its option argument is an open file descriptor *for that process*.
- `--switched-root` is used to tell this invocation of `systemd` that it has been invoked from [`systemd` managing an initramfs](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/InitrdInterface/), and so should behave accordingly — including turning *off* some of the behaviour otherwise caused by `--deserialize`.

Comment: It's a good answer. To expand on this a bit: systemd running with --deserialize --switched-root essentially means systemd was also used in the initramfs. Nowadays this is pretty common, so those two options are to be expected in the command line of PID 1.

Comment: @zbyszek So what's the point here?  If it's a good answer, why are those publicly exposed internal parts of `systemd` still no part in the official `systemd` documentation yet?  Shouldn't your explanation rather be included into the official `systemd` documentation to explain to us what we see (`systemd-cgls | grep deserialize`)?  It's 2020 already!  Are Google and SO really the only place, where such prominently publicly presented internal parts of `systemd` should be explained to minors like us?